# Unity 3D FileUtil.copyFileOrDirectory annoying exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I working in Unity 3d 2017.2.0f3 and Ineed to copy some files from a remote path to my local machine. So far I have something like this working:

```
 string  sourcePath= "\\\\SomeFolder\\SomeSubfolder\\SomeFile.png";
 string targetCachePath = "d:/SomeOtherFolder/SomeFile.png";
 FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(sourcePath, targetCachePath );
```

The point is that I need to copy the file to a subfolder into SomeOtherFolder so I need something like this:

```
string  sourcePath= "\\\\SomeFolder\\SomeSubfolder\\SomeFile.png";
string targetCachePath = "d:/SomeOtherFolder/SomeSubfolder/SomeFile.png";
FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(sourcePath, targetCachePath );
```

But as soon as I add "SomeSubfolder" in targetCachePath CopyFileOrDirectory stops working with an IOException: Failed to copy file /directory. I't annoying because I can't see any real difference from using a target path including a subfolder... as far as I know it should works... but it doesn't.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whats the exception and are you sure that the "SomeSubfolder" exsits and you have permissions to it

Comment: Thanks man. I had a typo in my SomeSubfolder string but I failed to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BugFinder said, make a check so the directory exists, also the Unity documentation say "All file separators should be forward ones "/"." so you might want to try and change your sourcePath.
Additionaly you can declare your strings as:

```
string  sourcePath= @"/SomeFolder/SomeSubfolder/SomeFile.png";
string targetCachePath = @"d:/SomeOtherFolder/SomeSubfolder/SomeFile.png";
FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(sourcePath, targetCachePath );
```

The @ in front of the value marks the string as a verbatim string literal - anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.

Best of luck with your progress!

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the  @ tip. Certainly useful!!